# angularjs detailed view page content is not loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a view with thumbs and they all have unique urls(numbered - {{items.indexOf(item)}} )
I am trying to load json data into detailed view but for some reason it is refusing to take data.

I have this controller:

```
app.controller('SubmissionViewCtrl', function($scope, http, $routeParams){
  $http.get('content.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.content = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
  });
});
```

and in my `submission-full.html` I have:

```
ng-model="content"
```

and

```
{{ item[whichItem].userName }}, {{ item[whichItem].doneAction }}
```

My [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nldsOSiat6pLhy1pC8ah?p=preview)

Could you have a look please and let me know what am I doing wrong and how to fix that?
Help is appreciated.

Comment: The plunker is a little confusing, can you try to explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for that. I am trying to load json data into detailed view. I have thumbs that should open in detailed view. For now I am just trying to load json in next step I would like to have different detailed views according to thumb type - image, article...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to this:

```
submissionControllers
   .controller('SubmissionViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 
                function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
```

change the `http` to `$http`.